# Asset Management web application?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there an open source asset management tool for controlling an organization's

- assets
- consumables
- and equipment ?

I was checking "Asset Manager", it is a commercial windows application but I would prefer a web based application.

Comment: currently this is a possible repeat/duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11619/web-based-inventory-management-system , please describe as much as you could about the requirements, data needed etc.

Comment: Thank you for your replay i will delete the first one and i really need this one thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should check [GLPI](http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en)  which's a free software webapps for managing IT ressources

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own Asset Manager web-app using [iFreeTools Creator](http://creator.ifreetools.com) defining your data-model, that is the entities ("tables") and attributes ("columns").

Once the data-model is defined, iFreeTools Creator will automatically provide the forms to enter data, which you can then view in list views and details view. You can create Custom Views too, providing filtering criteria.

Access control of the database (up to field level) is also possible and all database changes are automatically audited.

The web-app is built over Google App Engine and is free for up to 10 users (ad-supported) and requires nothing more than a Google user account to get started.

If you require assistance in getting started with your web-app, you can use the feedback form in iFreeTools Creator to request support.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but i just want a stand-alone application just install my company server and manage everything. Limitation? I don't like it.....  sorry.

Comment: It is okay.. in case your company decides to move on to online hosted apps, do give it a try.